# Bash, Awk dynamically matching shell variable (Darwin BSD)

Tags: regex, bash, shell, csv, awk

I have a series of .csv files that look similar to this:

```
Facility, Room, SN, Alert_Start, Alert_End
Foo, Bar, 28g63, 5/16/16 12:24, 5/30/16 12:24
Foo, Bar, 58dfy, 5/11/16 12:25, 5/30/16 12:24
Foo, Bar, dd8f6, 5/27/16 12:25, 5/30/16 12:24
Foo, Bar, 397d2, 5/24/16 12:24, 5/30/16 12:24
```

Each file is holding a different matched pair of "Room" and "Alert_End" values.

I am trying to arrange this .csv into a report in which a week's worth of "Room" and "Alert_End" pairings are contained in one file, with "SN" being the only other data showing. It needs to be arranged like this:

```
Room.csv
5/26/16, 5/27/16, 5/28/16, 5/29/16, 5/30/16, 5/31/16, 6/1/16
28g63, 28g63, 28g63, 28g63, 28g63, 28g63, 28g63
58dfy, 58dfy, 58dfy, 58dfy, 58dfy, 58dfy, 58dfy
     , dd8f6,     ,      ,       , dd8f6,
397d2, 397d2, 397d2, 397d2, 397d2, 397d2, 397d2
i58d7,      ,      ,      , i58d7, i58d7, i58d7
```

Here is the code block attempting to do the formatting:

```
function organizeText {
        for i in {0..6}; do
                day=$(date -v-${i}d +%Y-%m-%d)
                day2=$(date -v-${i}d +%m/%d/%yy)
                file=/tmp/$day"_$facility".csv
                echo $day > $file
                awk -F "," -v cow=$day2 '$5 ~ cow { print $3 }' "/tmp/$facility.csv" >> $file
        done

        touch "/tmp/master_$facility.csv"

        for i in {0..6}; do
                day=$(date -v-${i}d +%Y-%m-%d)
                paste -d, "/tmp/master_$facility.csv" /tmp/$day"_$facility".csv > "/tmp/master_$facility.csv"
        done
}
```

Whenever I try to run this, all of the '/tmp/$day"_$facility".csv' files contain the same full list of SN values associated with the facility, regardless of whether they match the date or not.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `date -v-${i}d +%m/%d/%yy` outputting what you need. I've tried it on two systems and the `-v` flag isn't recognized.

Comment: I'm using BSD date on Darwin BSD.

Comment: Your example file at the top has only 5 fields, but your test in `awk` is on `$8`. Is that a mistake in your code, or a bad example file?

Comment: @JNevil I've fixed this. It is a case of me trimming down the example CSV for readability. I have realigned the awk columns to fix the example text.

Comment: dd8f6 is missing for 28 and 29th . it the expected o/p correct?

Comment: @Chet Yes, I don't expect every SN to appear on every day.

Comment: So.. only on the alert start and end day

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out not to be my AWK, Bash, or regex code.

The problem was the way in which Microsoft Excel automatically formats and displays dates.

I was trying to write the regex to match what I was seeing in the .csv file as opened by Excel which formatted the dates like this:
    5/23/16

But when I opened the .csv file in a text editor, the date was actually formatted as a string like this:
    2016-05-23

I fixed my regex to match the formatting as shown via the text editor, and then the code worked.